# AWS Ubuntu 22.04 Interface Down on Reboot

Tags: networking, netplan, interface, aws, dhclient

Using Ubuntu 22.04.01 via AWS and just did a kernel update (among other items in `apt upgrade`) to 6.2.0-1017-aws and rebooted. Had to console in because connectivity was failing with no network changes. I then see that `ifconfig`'s output only shows the "lo" loopback interface running and not the one with the private IP on it. `ip a` shows that the interface exists but is down.

```
root@test:~# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 336  bytes 26160 (26.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 336  bytes 26160 (26.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
root@test:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:af:bd:fe:c2:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s5
```

Looking at the only netplan config file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, I see it is auto-generated by AWS's cloud services and gets rewritten on boot. I don't see any errors with it though. dhcp4 is set to true. Why wouldn't this interface start on boot like it did before the kernel update?

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: 12:af:bd:fe:c2:c3
            set-name: ens5
    version: 2
```

Running `dhclient` solves the problem and gives me the expected static private IP address every time. I don't even need to bring the interface up, it just does it for me.

```
root@test:~# dhclient
root@test:~# ifconfig
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.1.200 netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.31.1.255
        inet6 fe80::10af:bdff:fefe:c2c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:af:bd:fe:c2:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 680 (680.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 990 (990.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 496  bytes 38048 (38.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 496  bytes 38048 (38.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So I added `@reboot dhclient` to the crontab using `crontab -e` and now I don't have any issues on reboot. But WHY do I have to do this? I don't understand why the interface isn't just coming up on its own and I had to set dhclient to run on boot. This feels hacky. It solves the issue and I'm posting mainly to help others but I also want to understand the problem more and know if there's a better way.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `renderer:`.  https://netplan.io/

Comment: renderer is optional and defaults to networkd.

Comment: If you don't bring up the interface with `dhclient`, what does `networkctl` show as output?  This may explain why networkd failed to get an IP address with dhcp

Comment: root@test:~# networkctl
IDX LINK TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo   loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 ens5 ether    off         unmanaged

2 links listed.